# MySQL - how to paginate?

Tags: mysql

Given some records, how to query the following:

1. The first 10 records, the next 10 records, etc.?
2. The last 10 records, the second to the last 10 records, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **[`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)** clause.

Examples would be:

```
/** First 10 records **/
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY SomeColumn LIMIT 10; 
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY SomeColumn LIMIT 0,10; 
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY SomeColumn LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0; 

/** The records 11-20 **/
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY SomeColumn LIMIT 10, 10; 

/** The records 101-110 **/
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY SomeColumn LIMIT 100, 10; 
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY SomeColumn LIMIT 10 OFFSET 100; 

/** The last 10 records (in reverse order than previous queries) **/
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY SomeColumn DESC LIMIT 10; 
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY SomeColumn DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10;
```

Comment: Limit 10,100 will take 100 record starting at position 10. Not records 10-20.

Comment: Typing fast gets me sometimes, fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Still not right.. now you are getting records 100-110. "SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 10, 10; /** The records 10-20 **/"

Answer (score 2):

`LIMIT` is what you'll want http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

First 10:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT 10;
```

Second 10:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT 10,10;
```

Third 10:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT 20,10;
```

The "Last 10" only has a meaning when you are ordering the rows. In that case, you reverse the order, and take the first 10, using the first statement listed above. If you want "second to last 10" then you do the same with the order reversed and then use the second statement from above.

Hope that helps!

Comment: What if I want to maintain the order when I get the last 10?

Comment: Easy way is to just flip the order back once you have them, since there's only 10 that's fairly cheap to do. If you really want to do it in SQL, then you'll need to know the total number of rows so you can subtract 10 from that, and use it as your offset   `LIMIT (total-10),10`

Comment: How do I incorporate the total number of rows in the LIMIT part?

Comment: You'd get that information from outside of that query first. So run a COUNT() on that table, get the single row result. Store the information in a var, subtract 10 rom the count you have in that var, and then generate the new query, and execute it.

Comment: Sorta. Its not really worth the complexity tho. Last 5 rows: https://gist.github.com/1306594

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html#id989242) clause

- First 10 records

  ```
  ... LIMIT 10
  ```
- Next 10 records

  ```
  ... LIMIT 10, 10
  ```

Use this in combination with a `COUNT()` query in your application to find the total number of rows. You can then use this number and the number of desired rows per page to build your pagination.

Comment: Can you show how I would incorporate `COUNT()` when trying to get the last 10, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use LIMIT and OFFSET and ORDER BY to accomplish this.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: I want to maintain the order of the records when getting the last 10, second to the last 10, etc.

Answer (score 0):

one solution could be using limit 0,9 in your query

select * from table where id < 50 limit 0,9

then you put some buttons increasing / decreasing you limit

Answer (score 0):

PHP Code :

```
$limit = 10;
$page = 1;


$from = ( $page - 1 ) * $limit;
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT $from,$limit";
```